# Spinner in tab is not shown

Tags: android, tabs, spinner

This is my activity code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.input_transaction);

    tabHost = getTabHost();
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.tab_in))
                          .setIndicator(getString(R.string.tab_in))
                          .setContent(R.id.tab_in));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.tab_out))
                          .setIndicator(getString(R.string.tab_out))
                          .setContent(R.id.tab_out));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.tab_transfer))
                          .setIndicator(getString(R.string.tab_transfer))
                          .setContent(R.id.tab_transfer));
    tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(getString(R.string.tab_out));
}
```

Layout part for current tab

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab_out"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
              android:text="@string/planet_prompt"/>
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[And screen of what I got](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/69/screenshot5554android23.png/)

So, what should I do to make spinner present in tab, and why is it happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've told your text view to "Fill Parent", so it has pushed the spinner out.

Add this to both your spinner and textview XML:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: Oh, it seems it's the case. Thanks!
However, is there something like a firebug for android ui debug? :)

Comment: Nah, I wish, not for the layout part anyway (you do have logcat). Eclipse has a designer, but personally, I like to layout my XML by hand.